# video accelerator display trouble

Tags: screen, radeon, gnome-classic

I'm running 13.10 with Gnome-Fallback and a Trinity Radeon HD 7540 and I'm encountering flickering (among individual objects - not the whole display), screen regions being randomly shaded (in at least Firefox and LibreOffice Calc) and object drawing failures (the grid in a Calc document). These problems can be reliably reproduced.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The screen rendering problem was solved by installing the `fglrx` package.

It doesn't seem to have solved all of the flickering but it certainly has reduced it.